# iOS Flicker API to simply upload a public image?

Tags: ios, flickr, objectiveflickr

Is there suppose to be a Flickr API (provided by Flickr)?

If not, i see a couple of flickr "kits" on GitHub (objectiveflickr and flickrkit).
Which is preferred?

Or maybe it is better to just write my own custom routine (all i need to do is authenticate (if required) and upload an image)?

Your thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their website lists APIs.

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/

First hit on Google for **Flickr API**.

Comment: FYI, i did several searches on google. They all brought me to the 2 API/Kits i mentioned above.

Comment: Btw, the 2 API's mentioned for Objective C are the 2 that i mentioned in the OP. The question still remains open: which is preferred/advantageous?

Comment: This isn't a site for opinions; sorry.

Comment: I prefer FlickrKit because I wrote it !